# Why is my svg crossing the edge of it's parent div?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="LABEL_MAIN">
    <div class="LABEL_BOX">
        <div class="OP_LABEL">
            bro
        </div>                   
    </div>
<div class="outer-plus">
    <div class="inner-plus">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" 
                                    height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10" fill="none">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" 
                                      d="M5 0.5C5.25642 0.5 5.46775 0.69302 5.49664 
                                      0.941689L5.5 1V4.5H9C9.27614 4.5 9.5 4.72386 
                                      9.5 5C9.5 5.25642 9.30698 5.46775 9.05831 
                                      5.49664L9 5.5H5.5V9C5.5 9.27614 5.27614 9.5 5 
                                      9.5C4.74358 9.5 4.53225 9.30698 4.50336 
                                      9.05831L4.5 9V5.5H1C0.723858 5.5 0.5 5.27614 
                                      0.5 5C0.5 4.74358 0.69302 4.53225 0.941689 
                                      4.50336L1 4.5H4.5V1C4.5 0.723858 4.72386 0.5 5 
                                      0.5Z" fill="black"/>
                                </svg>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.LABEL_MAIN{
    display: flex;
    width: 247px;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 23px;
    border-bottom: 1px gray solid;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}

.LABEL_MAIN:last-child{
    border-bottom: none;
}

.LABEL_BOX{
    width: 247px; 
    justify-content: flex-start; 
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    align-items: center; 
    gap: 23px; 
    display: inline-flex
}

.OP_LABEL{
    width: 224px; 
    color: green; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    font-family: Bogle;
    font-weight: 400; 
    text-decoration: underline; 
    line-height: 20px; 
    word-wrap: break-word
}

.outer-plus{
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-end;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.inner-plus{
    padding: 3.50px;
    justify-content: flex-start; 
    align-items: flex-start; 
    display: inline-flex;
}


.plus{
    width: 9px; 
    height: 9px;
}
```

Below is my js fiddle, I am not sure why my svg goes outside the container and doesn't display fully. Below is the link of the code:

[Link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfdrxo72/)

How can I fix this? not sure what I am doing wrong

What it should look like:

[image]

I tried to remove padding in the LABEL_MAIN but that didn't help, I am not sure if display: inline-flex is the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you provided the `width: 247px` to the main div in `LABEL_MAIN` CSS class and then you applied the same width to the first child div in `OP_LABEL` CSS class. So the first child takes complete parent div width and SVG doesn't have enough space to show.

You can fix this problem by using one of the solutions:

Solution-1. Update the value of `width from 247px to 240px` in `OP_LABEL` CSS
class.

Solution-2. Add `justify-content: space-between` CSS property inside
`LABEL_MAIN` CSS class and remove `width: 247px` CSS property from
`OP_LABEL` CSS class.

```
.LABEL_MAIN{
    display: flex;
    width: 247px;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 23px;
    border-bottom: 1px gray solid;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.OP_LABEL{
    color: green; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    font-family: Bogle;
    font-weight: 400; 
    text-decoration: underline; 
    line-height: 20px; 
    word-wrap: break-word
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are making the `.LABEL_BOX` bigger than the container so, in order to solve it you have two ways.

**First Option**: remove the width of the `.LABEL_BOX` and then give the `.LABEL_MAIN` the property `justify-content: space-between;`.

**Second Option** do the math and make the `.LABEL_MAIN` fit with the SVG width + the gap or just decrease the gap to `18px` and call it a day.